# Adding values to a locally installed MSSQL DB in C++

Tags: c++, c, sql-server, windows

I looked this up and found a plethora of 3rd part libraries and such. I cannot choose which one I want to use. I really have no incredibly specific constraints to my project. I personally though would like to keep as little overhead as possible and code complexity down.

So what route do you sugggest I take to connect to a locally installed MSSQL DB, connect to it, and finally write values to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into ADO or ADO.NET? It's something like Microsoft's version of ODBC, and somewhat tailored to SQL Server.

ADO is a COM interface, but there are wrappers around it. ADO.NET is a managed interface. The best way to access ADO/ADO.NET depends on your background and on the application -- could you provide some more information on that, please?

[Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4033/using-ado-in-c/) is one rather dated but still valid tutorial for access via COM.

Comment: you should add information how to use ADO using C++